# Best method to rewrite complex SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE friend1='$username' OR friend2='$username' AND confirmed='1'");
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is delete from the table select data from the table `friends` where one of the two fields is equal to your username, and the `confirmed` field has to equal 1. This doesn't seem to be working though. What's the best way to rewrite it?

Comment: As the answers have pointed out, *always* put parenthesis around boolean conditions with mixed `OR`s and `AND`s, specifically to avoid this type of problem.  Future generations will thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with your friend clauses in parenthesis:

```
 SELECT * FROM friends 
 WHERE (friend1='$username' OR friend2='$username')
 AND confirmed='1'
```

This will ensure that one of your friend conditions is met. No matter which one matches, it'll also check the confirmed bit. If neither friend condition matches, the row isn't part of the resultset.

Comment: Agreed.  To explain, it could 'automatically' be interpreting your query as `friend1='$username' OR (friend2='$username' AND confirmed='1')`.

Comment: I believe that worked! If it doesn't I'll comment back. Thank you!

Comment: @p.campbell How about this: `mysql_query("DELETE FROM friends WHERE ((friend1='$username' OR friend2='$username') AND (friend1='$me' OR friend2='$me')) AND confirmed='0'");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your where clause is not evaluating the conditions in the way you expect? 
Try:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE (friend1='$username' OR friend2='$username') AND confirmed='1'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows operator precedence in mysql, as you can see AND is evaluated before OR , hence your problem.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/operator-precedence.html